# PHP 8: Assign "resource" as property, parameter, or return type

Tags: php, stream, php-8, psr-7

I am updating my project from PHP 7.0 to PHP 8.0 and I couldn't find out, if it is allowed to **EXPLICITLY** assign `resource` as the data type:

- of a ***class property***,
- of a ***method/function parameter***,
- ***returned by a method/function***,

What I know right now is, that:

- `resource` is one of the types building the [mixed type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.mixed),
- some internal functions, like [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), are returning the type `resource`.

Until now I read:

- all official manuals regarding migrating to PHP 8: [PHP: Migrating from PHP 5.5.x to PHP 5.6.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.php), ..., [PHP: Migrating from PHP 7.4.x to PHP 8.0.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php);
- The whole content on [PHP.Watch: PHP Versions](https://php.watch/versions);
- The whole content on [Lindevs: PHP](https://lindevs.com/category/php/).

Am I missing something, somewhere?

Thank you for your time.

---

For more clarity, this is how I want to use the `resource` data type in my project (PSR-7 implementation):

```
<?php

namespace MyPackages\Http\Message;

use Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface;

/**
 * Stream.
 */
class Stream implements StreamInterface {

    /**
     * A stream, e.g. a resource of type "stream".
     *
     * @var resource
     */
    private resource $stream;

    /**
     * @param string|resource $stream A filename, or an opened resource of type "stream".
     * @param string $accessMode (optional) Access mode. 'r': Open for reading only.
     */
    public function __construct(string|resource $stream, string $accessMode = 'r') {
        $this->stream = $this->buildStream($stream, $accessMode);
    }

    /**
     * Build a stream from a filename or an opened resource of type "stream".
     *
     * Not part of PSR-7.
     *
     * @param string|resource $stream Filename, or resource.
     * @param string $accessMode Access mode.
     * @return resource
     * @throws \RuntimeException If the file cannot be opened.
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the stream or the access mode is invalid.
     */
    private function buildStream(string|resource $stream, string $accessMode): resource {
        if (is_string($stream)) {
            //... some validations ...

            /*
             * Open the file specified by the given filename.
             * E.g. create a stream from the filename.
             * E.g. create a resource of type "stream" from the filename.
             */
            try {
                $stream = fopen($stream, $accessMode);
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('The file "' . $stream . '" could not be opened.');
            }
        } elseif (is_resource($stream)) {
            if ('stream' !== get_resource_type($stream)) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The provided resource must be an opened resource of type "stream".');
            }
        }

        return $stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot type hint with `resource`.

Here's an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/resource_typehint) from 2015 where it was brought up, here's the [PR](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1631) with the implementation, and here's a [thread of discussion](https://externals.io/message/89165#89355) on it.

The gist is that the PHP community wants to get rid of resources because they represent an older way of doing things. Also, `resource` is too generic, basically equivalent to `object` that it doesn't provide much, if any benefit.

From the discussion:

> The reason for this is that the resource type is an anachronism from an
> age in which PHP did not have objects, yet still needed to make certain
> types of data opaque. The resource type is a type that exists only to
> shuffle around C pointers between internal functions. It has no semantic
> value. Because resources are now redundant, given the existence of
> objects, their time is running out, and they will be replaced at some
> point. Adding a type declaration for resource would mean that code using
> it would break if we replace any existing usage of resources with
> objects, preventing migration away from resource
>
> Andrea Faulds

And

> The long term plan is to do transitions similar to the one which GMP
> underwent: It uses GMP objects since PHP 5.6 and was using resources
> previously.
>
> ...
>
> In addition to what Andrea said (resource type hint causing issues should
> we choose to migrate to objects), I also think that the resource type hint
> provides relatively little value in itself. It only says that you are
> accepting some resource. However, resources are many. Is this a file
> handle? Is it a database connection? Is it a streaming hash context? It
> doesn't tell.
>
> Nikita Popov

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I just read some of the posts. Indeed, good arguments for not (bothering) allowing `resource` as type-hint.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to declare it as 'mixed'.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php

mixed is equivalent to the union type object|resource|array|string|int|float|bool|null. Available as of PHP 8.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for static analysis or whatever, you can declare it as mixed and then narrow that type by using a docblock, which allows the type, kinda like you have done. For example:

```php
/**
 * @var resource $stream
 */
private mixed $stream;
```

Or as a return type:

```php
/**
 * @return resource
 */
function myFunc(): mixed
{
    //...
}
```

Now the type is more correctly shown for example in vscode:

- [Image of example Class displayed in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC2Ym.png)
- [Image of type hover of property in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqWGp.png)
- [Image of type hover of function in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN881.png)

Keep in mind though that this is more about aesthetics/optics.